# GeoServer Cascading WMS Passthrough Styles

Tags: geoserver

I am using the External Web Map Server capability in GeoServer to cascade a WMS. The WMS supports 5 styles declared in the GetCapabilities response. How do you make GeoServer forward the styles parameter to the external WMS? The GetMap requests to the external WMS are not including a styles parameter.

Comment: According to the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html#cascaded-wms-settings) the styles should be passed through. Can you add details of the service you are using and the request you are making. You can also add the relevant section of the log file with debugging turned upto GEOTOOLS-DEV

Comment: There are 5 styles declared in the root Layer in the GetCapabilities response.  Each Style has a Title, Name and Abstract. I know the styles work when I make GetMap requests directly to the WMS, but cascaded requests are not forwarding the styles query string parameter.

Comment: If they are not declared in the layer you are requesting then I don't think GeoServer will recognise them

Comment: The Styles are declared in the root Layer. GeoServer Logs confirms that GeoServer gets the incoming styles param value, and that it passes "styles=" with no value in the outgoing requests. When the incoming styles parameter is set to an advertised style, the request completes but GS passes "styles=". When incoming styles parameter is set to unknown value, e.g., styles=foobar, GS has a StyleNotDefined service exception. It seems like GS is aware of the advertised styles and only accepts those values, but it does not forward the incoming styles param value.

Comment: The advertised styles have Name, Title and Abstract (optional). They do not include LegendURL, StyleSheetsURL or StyleURL, which are also optional according to WMS 1.3.0 standard. I don't know if this is relevant or not. Observed behavior does not match what GeoServer documentation predicts.

Comment: Upgraded to GeoServer 2.20.0. I now see the error "unable to fetch remote styles for faa:aero-chart", where "faa:aero-chart" is the name of the Layer that contains five <Style> tags. However, there's no clue as to why GeoServer can parse Name, Title, CRS, etc., but fails to parse the Style nodes.

Comment: I searched for WMS GetCapabilities validators and I found uDig Version: 1.5.0.RC1 - http://udig.refractions.net/download/. uDig says the GetCapabilities response is valid. It parses all 5 styles and presents each as a "WMS Named Style". It uses style titles in the UI and style names in the requests, and is able to display maps with all 5 styles.

Comment: Can you add details of the service you are using and the request you are making. You can also add the relevant section of the log file with debugging turned upto GEOTOOLS-DEV

Comment: The GetCapabilities response is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MJMcC5koDsSItjgmTcXgMlckb6-aMGkT/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: After adding the External WMS as a Store, the New Layer page shows all the layers. "faa:aero-chart" is the Name of the root Layer. All other layers are child Layer nodes under the root Layer.

[Screen Shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-I5FTXXUDPcx6IPXecCirHwyjjbHhbez/view?usp=sharing)

5 Style nodes are also under the root Layer node. While it is clear that GeoServer parses keywords, abstracts, CRS, Layer nodes, etc., it seems to ignore the Style nodes.

Comment: After publishing the "faa:aero-chart" layer and going to the [Tile Caching tab](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R-Pgd28Wzn3YHVVq54i3XGae1fpLIulo/view?usp=sharing) for that layer, you only see LAYER DEFAULT as the only style option.